# Using sed to remove lines till the end of the file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm using `sed -n '/[test1]/,/[test2]/{/[test2]/!p}' test.txt > temp.txt`  ..which works well if If I only want the top selection, but I'm after the bottom section.

```
[test1]
A
B
C
[test2]
1
2
3
```

But I'm after [test2] onwards, so Copying [test2] till the end of the line. So producing an output like so,

```
[test2]
1
2
3
```

Comment: I think there's a grep option that outputs just the line number. You process that and send it to tail maybe?

Comment: So what exactly is your expected output from above file? Do you just want output like you wrote in lower section of your question.

Comment: `sed -n '/\[test2\]/,$p'` is what you're looking for probably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sed -n  '/\(^\[test2\]\)/,$p' test.txt > temp.txt
```

**Edit**:

With extended regular expression flag(`-r`),

```
 sed -n -r '/(^\[test2\])/,$p' test.txt > temp.txt
```

Comment: I've got to remember that... could come in handy.  Separately, while kudos are deserved for accuracy and attention to detail, I suggest that this alternative might be a little more legible: `sed -n '/test2/,$p' < /tmp/file`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `grep -n` will output the line number and match, and processing it I came up with the following

```
 grep -n '\[test2\]' temp.txt | awk -F\: '{print "sed \"1,"$1-1"d;\" temp.txt"}' | bash > test.txt
```

so a cat of the new file produces the following:

```
 cat test.txt
 [test2]
 1
 2
 3
```

btw, `| bash`
redirects formatted command lines with `awk` to `bash` in order to execute them